# Cómo insertar impresos de una tabla, e insertar el id a otra usando checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, checkbox

Hola buena tarde soy algo nuevo en formularios con php y base de datos y lo que intento hacer es usar checkboxes para seleccionar un producto. Tengo 2 tablas una llamada `plenitud_productos` y otra `plenitud_pedidos`, la tabla de productos ya tiene registros y los precios, sólo uso esta para imprimir al navegador esos datos. La tabla de pedidos almacenará dicha información mediante un formulario, pero con una columna adicional, que es la de "cantidad".

Esta es la manera en la cuál estoy imprimiendo los nombres y los precios, tengo diferentes nombres para estos en el formulario y en las columnas de la tabla en la base de datos, estos son:

Tipo = se refiere a el nombre del producto, y donativo = precio.

```
                        <div class="consult-table-data" id="scroll">
                            <?php while($productos_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productos_result)) { ?>
                                <div class="display-data-order" data-products="<?php echo "{$productos_row['tipo']}" ;?> <?php echo "{$productos_row['donativo']}" ;?>">
                                    <span> <input type="checkbox" name="producto[]" value="<?php echo $productos_row{['id']} ?>"> <?php echo "{$productos_row['tipo']}" ;?> </span>
                                    <span> $ <?php echo "{$productos_row['donativo']}" ;?> </span>
                                    <span> <input class="input-prod-quantity" type="text" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" require> </span>
                                </div> <!-- Display data -->

                            <?php } ?> <!-- While loop END -->
```

Problemática

1) Al momento de yo querer usar dicho formulario debo de ingresar la cantidad del producto en un input tipo text, y el producto mediante un checkbox, pues bien, al momento de seleccionar algún producto y de escribir la cantidad, o el número no se inserta nada en la tabla.

Estos son los queries de insercción que he utilizado:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit_order'])) {
    $miembro = $_POST['miembro'];
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $producto = $_POST['producto'];
    $b = implode(", ", $producto);

    $nuevo_pedido = "INSERT INTO plenitud_pedidos (miembro, grupo, nombre_producto)
    VALUES ('$miembro', '$grupo', '$b')";

    $pedido_result = mysqli_query($conn, $nuevo_pedido);

    $_SESSION['added'] = 'Nuevo pedido añadido';
    header("Location: ../pedidos.php");
}
```

Este viene siendo el error SQL cuando trato de correr la consulta hacia la base de datos:

```
#1366 - Incorrect integer value: '$grupo' for column `plenitud_organizador`.`plenitud_pedidos`.`grupo` at row 1
```

Adjunto imagen:
[image: Columnas SQL]

Comment: El mensaje de error te dice que el valor de la columna grupo está mal. Te convendría validar todos los datos antes de incluirlos en una consulta y, de paso, migrar a consultas preparadas para evitar riesgos de inyección SQL y errores por no escapar los datos.

Comment: ¿Con valor te refieres a que la variable está mal, o que debería cambiar el tipo de columna? Que en este caso es una foreign key. Las inyecciones SQL es una de las cosas que todavía no he podido implementar porque todavía no sé cómo, pero si uno de importancia, gracias por recordármelo. Saludos

Comment: Sin ver tu formulario será difícil saber, pero puede ser que no tengas un campo para grupo o el valor no es el adecuado.

Comment: El valor del campo `grupo` en plenitud_pedidos es un entero, y le agregé un índice o una foreign key, esto para insertar datos desde otra tabla, y lo mismo con nombre_producto sólo que esta vez con nombres de productos. Al momento de querer insertar datos y recibir ese mensaje de "error", estaba usando una variable, esa consulta la obtuve desde el código php que estoy desarrollando, únicamente quería probar si la consulta tenía algún error y cerciorarme de que los checkboxes estaban alineados con los datos impresos de la tabla "plenitud_productos". Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, y en parte creo Triby tenía razón, aunque no me especificó o sugirió algún tipo de valor a cambiar en la columna "grupo". Cambié el valor de la columna de INT a CHAR, y funciónó desde SQL y desde el formulario. Gracias Triby!